# Impacts of Updating jvm?

Tags: java, database, oracle

When running this script:

*@?/javavm/install/update_javavm_db.sql*

Is this gonna affect the users? Do I need to change the state of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to change the state of the database. You should not run that script without first shutting down your database, please see the Oracle documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chone.htm#JJDEV01600

> With an Existing Database
>
> If you have installed Oracle Database 12c
> Release 1 (12.1) Server in your system with an ORACLE_HOME, and have
> created a database with JDK version x, then follow these steps to
> change the JDK version to y:
>
> **Shutdown all the Databases running with the ORACLE_HOME.**
>
> Note:For Windows platform, you must stop all the Oracle Services
> corresponding to the specific ORACLE_SID as well.

Shutting down the database will impact users as it will end all ongoing sessions.